# Java 8 --- Lambda Expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, expression

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class LambdaExpression {


    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static Function create(int addTo){
        int n = 1;
        Function<Integer, Integer> f = addT -> addTo + n;

        return f;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(LambdaExpression.create(5));
    }
}
```

Giving me this error during runtime:

> LambdaExpression$$Lambda$1/424058530@1c20c684

Comment: What makes you think that's an error? You've created a `Function`, and you're trying to print the function itself, implicitly calling `toString()`... that's giving you a relatively-unreadably (but not incorrect) string value.

Comment: Is that an error or is that just the output of your program?

Comment: output of my program

Comment: the program should add 1 to every input

Comment: No, the program currently creates a function which *ignores* its input, and returns `addTo + 1` regardless.

Comment: It's also not clear why you're returning a raw `Function` unnecessarily...

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept of a lambda expression.

Comment: You may have meant to use `LambdaExpression.create(5).apply(6)`.

Comment: Buddy, you are printing a function instead of its returned value that's why you are getting this output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to create a function which adds 1 to its input, the method to *create* that function doesn't need an parameters... but then you need to *call* that function in order to execute it. I suspect you wanted:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class LambdaExpression {
    public static Function<Integer, Integer> create() {
        Function<Integer, Integer> f = x -> x + 1;    
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<Integer, Integer> f = create();
        System.out.println(f.apply(5)); // 6
    }
}
```

If you *actually* want a function which adds whatever you pass to the create method (instead of always adding 1) that's easy:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class LambdaExpression {
    public static Function<Integer, Integer> create(int addTo) {
        Function<Integer, Integer> f = x -> x + addTo;
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<Integer, Integer> f = create(3);
        System.out.println(f.apply(5)); // 8
    }
}
```

Comment: /AdderFactoryTest.java:9: error: method create in class AdderFactory cannot be applied to given types;
5, AdderFactory.create(1).applyAsInt(4));
^
required: no arguments
found: int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Comment: import java.util.function.Function;

public class AdderFactory {
  /*
   * Make the "create" method (public, static). It accepts one parameter (int addTo) and returns
   * a function (make sure to use the appropriate type). This function accepts an integer,
   * adds "addTo" to that integer, and returns the result as an integer (integer-to-integer function).
   */
  public static Function<Integer, Integer> create() {
    Function<Integer, Integer> f = x -> x + 1;
    return f;
  }
}

Comment: @RonOhare: You said you wanted a function which always adds 1. Why would you want a parameter for that? See my edit for what you might want though. It's very hard to answer when you haven't really asked a question clearly though...

Comment: you solution works and I have tried it in eclipse. however, system is looking for something specific which i don't know yet. Thanks much for the help on lambda expression.

Comment: @RonOhare: What do you mean by "system"? We have zero context here. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints to help you ask clearer questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour.

There was a deliberate attempt to obscure the `toString()` of a lambda to avoid being dependant on the inner workings of how lambdas were implemented. They want the ability to change the implementation of lambdas and not have to support `toString`.  While I don't agree with this approach, it doesn't make it an error.